# Minimum operations to make K Non Decreasing Array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

LinkPark's OA Question. I am trying for days to come up with decent approach which is not exponential.  I am hoping you can suggest a direction to explore.

PS: Let me know if this is not right place to ask ds/algo questions.

[image]

Comment: This is the right place to ask alg/ds questions but pasting a picture instead of writing down the problem and what you have tried is a low-effort, do-it-for-me red flag. I'd like to help but this way it would be counter productive.

Comment: This problem is K separate largest-non-decreasing-subsequence problems, and that already has answers in SO.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I believe problem is far more complicated than simply finding k separate non decreasing subsequence.

Comment: It's not.  For each a < K, the longest non-decreasing subsequence of elements at indexes a + Ki, are the plants you don't need to change.  The rest need to be changed.